# Apache Cordova GeoLocation not providing data

Tags: javascript, apache, cordova, geolocation

I'm using Apache Cordova to get the lat and long coordinates of a device to pass on to a parse database. However, the coordinates are returning blank and no error alert appears. JSFiddle shows no syntax errors.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
var lat1=""; var long1="";

// Cordova is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
 alert("Device is ready!");
}

// onSuccess Geolocation
function onSuccess(position) {
    long1=position.coords.longitude;
    lat1=position.coords.latitude;
}

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
function onError(error) {
    alert("unable to get location");
}

function options(){ enableHighAccuracy: true }
```

Comment: After adding an `alert` command in the `onDeviceReady` function, and not seeing an alert, I have concluded that the error pertains to the device being  not "ready". Not sure what to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you made this inverted:

Change:

```
position.coords.longitude=long1;
position.coords.latitude=lat1;
```

To:

```
long1 = position.coords.longitude;
lat1 = position.coords.latitude;
```

Comment: Thank you. I corrected that but it's still not passing any data. After adding an `alert` command in the `onDeviceReady` function, and not seeing an alert, I have concluded that the error pertains to the device being  not "ready". Not sure what to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by explicitly installing the plugin: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation`

However, I'm using `$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition`, not `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`.

Hope this help you! :)