# Cordova Geolocation returning empty

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, geolocation

This is repeat of 
[Apache Cordova GeoLocation not providing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356589/apache-cordova-geolocation-not-providing-data)

Following code returns an empty object:

```
function onDeviceReady(){
    $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition({}).then(function(resp) {
      console.log(resp);
      $scope.geo.get = resp;
    });
  }
```

No errors or anything, just empty `{}`

**Update 1**

Works fine Samsung S3, but doesnt work on Nexus 4.

**Update 2**

LogCat shows the following line:

```
Caught security exception registering for location updates from the system.
```

Comment: Not exactly relevant since I cant replicate the device or anything of that sort

Comment: cordova doesn't provide any code for the geolocation, it just uses the webview implementation, so if it works on some devices and fail in others, it's a problem with the device or android version

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you added the corresponding `location` permissions.
If you are using iOS, it might ask you if you want to allow the app to determine your location.

If you are not sure, check the settings on both devices (android/ios) to check the requested permissions.

Comment: I checked permission, app seems to be allowed. It shows the app in recent location request.

Comment: Can you use Weinre or Chrome dev tools (android 4.4.4+) or safari web inspector to see maybe there are some errors that are being displayed?

Comment: There are some unaddressed CORS issues to deal in Chrome effectively. However I noticed this, when i use other apps with Geolocation from AppStore. Geo icon appears in the top bar, when I turn this one on, it doesnt.

Comment: Correction, it does appear but for a split moment. Since it is get cur position and not watch, i guess?

Comment: I think it's the CORS.. This is what I was suspecting.. Especially since Cordova 5 (they moved it to a separate plugin)

Comment: CORS is not an issue outside Chrome. When I push it to the device or phonegap app, its not. Plus how can it be, if I am not even pushing data outside the phone, just trying to display it.

Comment: I have 2 more suggestions: 1) Cordova platform remove ios (or Android) then re add it.
If that doesn't work try to use the plugin under window.plugins rather than the $Cordova wrapper